# Finding path between two nodes in Neo4j via Cypher is slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I intend to find the path between two nodes:

```
MATCH (x:Column {name:'colA', schema:'a.b'})-[cd:CD*1..]->(y:Column {name:'colB', schema:'c.d'})
RETURN x,y;`
```

and the explain is illustrated below:

[image]

After executing the above cypher, it looks like stuck forever without returning anything. I think the culprit is the VarLengthExpand phase, the Neo4j version is `enterprise-3.4.0`, any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, upgrade. You're using a .0 release, and these are usually the most buggy kinds of releases (aside from the alphas). At the least, get to the latest patch release for the minor version you're interested in (so in your case, if you want 3.4.x, get the latest patch along the 3.4.x line).

Secondly, as both of these nodes can be looked up via the index, and as it seems you're only looking for a single path, not all possible paths, you may want to make use of [shortestPath()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path) after matching upon both of the nodes. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (x:Column {name:'colA', schema:'a.b'}), (y:Column {name:'colB', schema:'c.d'})
MATCH path = (x)-[:CD]->(y)
RETURN path
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.